# iOS 11 - Use large titles as a navigation (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, navigation, ios11

I recently found an app with a really interesting navigation (utilizing the large titles in iOS11) I want to adapt into my private app. So I started searching for a way to create it but I didn't find out how to create multiple large titles that are linked with the current "page" so you could just click any of the entries to get to the actual page.

I uploaded a video to YouTube showing the navigation, so you can understand it better: https://youtu.be/IAaxhjWmDQ0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAaxhjWmDq0

Comment: I'd guess it isn't using a navigation bar but just has a custom view styled to look the same as one.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have LargeTitles on iOS Navigation bar on Swift4, you need to set this option to true

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

and then, set always display the content of large title

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```

additional if you want to customize the title of navigation bar, you need to set the appereance

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().prefersLargeTitles = true
UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = 
    [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue, 
     NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Papyrus", size: 30) ?? 
                                 UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)]
```

"Papyrus" is the font custom in the project

credits to: https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/large-titles-ios-11/

Comment: Hey dude, please watch the video before just telling me how to create a simple large title.